# implement accordion into wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i've seen a jsfiddle accordion that works exactly how i'd like for my website:

http://jsfiddle.net/DkHyd/

```
<h1>Toggle Panels</h1>
<div id="notaccordion">
  <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris  ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus  nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a  nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur  malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula.  Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet,  mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.  Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac,  risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede.  Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed  commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo  purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item  three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique  senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante  ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;  Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer  dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per  conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to implement this into wordpress to create pages with such accordions?

thanks

Comment: This is really beyond what you can reasonably expect people to answer on Stack Overflow. You aren't having a problem with writing it, you are asking someone else to go out and write a big section of your site. There are tons of how-to's for creating and modifying Wordpress themes. Find a how-to, modify your theme, and come back if you have trouble implementing it. If that's beyond you, then there are some sites where people will write custom wordpress themes (for a fee).

Answer (score 0):

Make a few pages.
Run a [query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and in each one add

```
<h3><a href="#"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    <?php the_content();?>
    </p>
  </div>
```